# Map -spec in erlang

Tags: dictionary, erlang, specifications

I'm looking to use the new erlang maps in a project, but I want to make sure to properly `-spec` everything I do. So my question is, what's the syntax for this? Is there anything like there is for records where I can specify field types? Or do I just use `map()` (and is that even the correct type spec?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `map()` is one way to specify a map type. Another is `#{}`, which like `map()` means a map of any size. You can also specify `#{ Type => Type }` with one or more `Type => Type` pairs, as described in the [Erlang Types and Function Specifications page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). Also, have a look at the `can_pkt()` type in the [source code for the maps1 test](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/dialyzer/test/small_SUITE_data/src/maps1.erl) in the Erlang source code, as that specifies a record-like map type.

Comment: I had looked at the types and functions page, but was looking for a section on maps. Didn't think to look in the general area. Thanks!

Comment: An important point from the [Erlang Types and Function Specifications page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) is that a mandatory association looks like `#{ T1 := T2 }`, e.g. a map that always only maps atoms to strings is `#{ atom() := string() }`.

Comment: @SimonShine Do you know if `#{ T1 := T2 }` allows for empty maps as well?

Comment: @filmor: I would certainly assume so. Empty maps are trivially polymorphic.